# How can I take my CSS custom cursor out of the document flow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Take a look at my code: https://codepen.io/duncanbritt/pen/LYdXVJY and direct your attention to this snippet of CSS:

```css
.precursor::after {
    position: relative;
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background:rgb(179, 2, 2);
    display: inline-block;
    animation: cursor-blink 1.5s steps(2) infinite;
}
```

Currently, if you click on a character in the right pane of my web page, a cursor appears between it and the previous character. I would like for the cursor to not effect anything else in the document, but to still be tethered to the prior character.

If I simply change .precursor::after { position: absolute }, it looks great until I scroll. What can I do to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**
Use
`.precursor::after{ position: absolute; }`
as you mentioned. And just add

```
.precursor{ position: relative; }
```

to your style-sheet and it will work.

**Explanation:**
This works because the element with `position: absolute` positions itself in relation to the nearest ancestor who has `position: absolute` or `position: relative`. By defining the position of the parent element as relative we are limiting the ::after pseudo element.